# I'm hitting a wall with this tiny avr programmer stick I'm using to program attiny85 chips

Tags: avr

I bought a few of these Tiny AVR programmers and nothing I read about this thing is up to date. I think I may need some newer drivers or something because the ArduinoIDE can't see my programmer. But also I couldn't get it to work with a standard Arduino mega board hooked up to a breadboard. I wired everything correctly but it errored out when uploading to the attiny85.

[This is the tinyAVRprogrammer](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0BK9P76BH)

Here are the stats I could get from the store page:

> Type: USB A Male Port
>
> It can shrink your Arduino projects down to "Tiny Size".
> Easy to use for programming ATTiny ICs (ATTiny85, ATTiny45, ATTiny13A, etc.)
>
> 3 In 1 Solution: 1) Program a socketed chip, 2) Connect a socketed chip in the programmer to a breadboard with jumper wires for prototyping, 3) Program a chip in-circuit (e.g. an SO8).
> Professional design, Flexible, stable performance and easy to install."

[This the Tutorial I had the most luck with](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/tiny-avr-programmer-hookup-guide/all#driver-installation)

It works until I try to upload the sketch to the attiny85 chip but when the terminal should start waiting for 60 seconds for a chip to be connected it just says no programmer detected and fails. The guide says the drivers are probably the problem but I have double checked and as far as I can tell the driver installed fine they just don't work because this guide and all related downloads are for Arduino 1.6 at the latest.

I did manage to troubleshoot the attiny core board addon bug that prevents IDE from finding the add on so that is for sure up to date but thats only bit I know for sure that is currently compatible with the 2.2.1 version of the IDE.

Comment: There's [arduino.se] which may be a better place to ask this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try this workaround: from "sketch" menu -> "upload using programmer" instead of using the "upload" button. ATtiny85 (and companions) has no bootloader, while standard boards have bootloader, that is used when you upload a sketch from the Arduino IDE.

You can find more about it here:

https://forum.arduino.cc/t/uploading-to-attiny85-gives-error-a-programmer-is-required-to-upload/1065582/3

and GitHub:

https://github.com/arduino/arduino-ide/issues/103